# Legend for tables

Tags: tables, captions, subcaption

I am trying to generate tables similar to the one attached here. Basically, one main caption on the top, and some extra descriptions in the legend below the table.

**EDIT:** Thank you for the comment. Yes, I am looking for a legend for tables. The font size should be smaller and the width should be the same as the tabular material (similar to the image below).

[image]

Comment: What you describe is generally called a legend, not a subcaption, to the tabular material. Please provide more information about how you would like the legend to be formatted. E.g., should it use a small font size than the main part of the table does? Should the width of the legend be the same as that of the tabular material? Any other requirements? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico thanks for your comment. I just updated the question.

Comment: Either use a `\multicolumn` or the `threeparttable` environment.

Comment: With footnotes (tablenotes) definitely use threeparttable.

Comment: Do you have any news for us? Is the issue solved? How?